# How to simplify multiple if-else conditions with boolean algebra?

Tags: boolean-logic

The question is which `if-else` branch in the following code is redundant?

```
if (x<3 && y>3)
    printf("Test OK!\n");
else if (x>=3 && y>=3)
    printf("Test OK!\n");
else if (z>3 && x>=3)
    printf("Test OK!\n");
else if (z<=3 && y>=3)
    printf("Test OK!\n");
else
    printf("Test failed!\n");
```

my thought is considering conditions as events:

```
x<3 -> p
y>3 -> q
y>=3 -> m
z>3 -> n
```

and the question is equivalent to pick redundant one from:

```
p＊q
^p＊q
n＊^p
^n＊m
```

however since `p q n m` are not independent events I'm really stuck. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: None of them, as far as I can see. The general technique is to draw up a truth table with `x,y,z` as `< 3` or >= 3` and see which rows are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks @EJP but the problem is there're `y>3` and `y>=3` in the condition branches, I don't know how to draw truth table for `y`?

Comment: So you need to allow three values for `y`.

Comment: Ok got it, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to simply remove a single `if` condition and have it working the same, then I don't think you could do that with this set. That said, I took a shot at the boolean reduction and it did simplify the `if-else` cases.

First, let's think about `y>3` as `y>=3 && y!=3`. This makes your first `if` case

```
if (x<3 && y>=3 && y!=3)
```

Since my brain works better with the greater-than signs facing the same way, I'll redefine your conditions to be:

```
X: x>=3
Y: y>=3
A: y!=3
Z: z>3
```

Now, your `if-then` cases can be written in boolean algebra as:

```
^XYA + XY + ZX + ^ZY
```

This is my truth table where `Q` is the result of the above boolean equation
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzVJi.png)

And my [Karnaugh Map](https://youtu.be/UdpV-ksadkQ): [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GChtG.png)

Which reduced the equation to:

```
YA + ZX + ^ZY
```

And back into code

```
if (y>3)
    printf("Test OK!\n");
else if (z>3 && x>=3)
    printf("Test OK!\n");
else if (z<=3 && y>=3)
    printf("Test OK!\n");
else
    printf("Test failed!\n");
```

Comment: Wow that's exactly what I'm looking for! The 'canonical' way of solving such problems! Thank you so much for your time and effort sir!